# Transformar boolean de sql a boolean java?

Tags: java, mysql, booleano

Estoy en un problema, tengo un `SELECT`que pide `ususario (int)`, `contraseña (String)`y `tipo (boolean)`de una base de datos, los guardo en un `Object [][]`, hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando quiero guardar esos 3 valores en otras variables separadas por su tipo, la `int`y la `String`guardan bien, pero el `boolean` nunca toma el `1` que le llega como un `true`, o sea que siempre esta en `false`

código:

```
result.next();{

                datosObt[0][0] = result.getString( "usuario" );
                datosObt[0][1] = result.getString( "contraseña" );
                datosObt[0][2] = result.getString( "tipo" );//es 1
                //aquí es donde obtengo los 3 datos y los guardo en el Object[][]
                }
            result.close();
            //me salto el catch para la pregunta


            //abajo los paso a los distintos tipos en los que necesito
            userObt= Integer.parseInt(datosObt[0][0].toString());
            pwdObt= datosObt[0][1].toString();
            tipoObt= Boolean.parseBoolean(datosObt[0][2].toString());//es 1 pero el tipoObt permanece false
```

Como digo, las dos primeras "transformaciones" funcionan bien, pero la tercera a `boolean`no ha querido funcionar. Espero me puedan dar una mano. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar los métodos del `ResultSet`, te ahorrarías completamente la conversión de cada valor, por ejemplo para obtener "usuario" sólo debes de utilizar el método `result.getInt("usuario")` que en automático te devuelve un entero y para un boolean:

```
boolean b = result.getBoolean("tipo");
```

Te recomiendo leer la [API-ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) para que veas todos los métodos que te ofrece, saludos.

Comment: voy a intentar con éste método , muchas gracias

Comment: capaz que no se entendió o no me di a entender, `Object [][]` es un array objeto, y la conversión `result.getInt("usuario")` como las siguientes, me dan el `error: "no se puede convertir de Object a int"`
Al hacerlo recordé que no me habia funcionado así.

Comment: Todo solcionado: no uso el `Object [][]` y guardo directamente en las 3 variables que necesito, así si guarda `int` con `result.getInt("usuario")` y así correlativamente. No lo pensé así antes por apegarme a lo que la "docente" (por llamarla de alguna manera) dio en clase. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: La forma correcta sería usando los respectivos métodos que te indiqué, por el código que proporcionas te recomiendo no usar el array tipo `Object [ ] [ ]` no le veo utilidad usarlo(hacer directamente `tipoObt = result.getBoolean("tipo") funcionaría`).

Comment: hice exactamente eso, saqué el array y deje las variables. como decimos por acá: muerto el perro se acabó la rabia. no hay array que complique no hay complicación. :D

Answer (score 0):

El método de la wrapper class de Boolean convierte un String a boolean, pero lo que espera es un "true" o "false".

Como a ti te está llegando 0 o 1 tendrás que hacerlo a mano, es decir comprobar Si lo que te viene es un 1 o un 0 y setear un valor. Puedes usar un operador ternario para evitar líneas de código. Quedaría algo así:

```
tipoObt= datosObt[0][2] == "1" ? true : false;
```

Tendrías que comprobar que datosObt[0][2] no es nulo y todo ese tipo de validaciones, pero así te funcionará.

Comment: gracias, lo hice por algo parecido, simplemente controlando si `equals("1")` y funciona, `not null`está controlado desde la creación de la tabla, asi que nunca va a estar sin dato alguno. pero voy a intentar con el método que me dio Luís. igual gracias!!